# Direction ambiguity of the angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, angular-velocity

**The problem:**

A common "definition" for the angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$ is:
$$ \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}.$$

However, this says nothing about the direction of $\vec{\omega}$ except that it's on a plane orthogonal to $\vec{v}$. Taking the cross product of $\vec{v}$ with $\vec{r}$ and using the triple product yields
$$ \vec{\omega} = \frac{\vec{r}\times\vec{v} + (\vec{r}\cdot\vec{\omega})\vec{r}}{r^2},$$

which is ill-defined.

Imagine a point particle at some position in the $yz$ plane: $\vec{r} = (0,y,z)$ where $y$ and $z$ are nonzero. We measure the velocity for a very short time and see that it's pointing in the $(-\hat{x})$ direction: $\vec{v} = (-v,0,0)$.

We don't know if the particle is circling about the $z$ axis or the $y$ axis (or a combination of the two) since we only glimpsed at its velocity for an infinitesimal time. The only condition we have to satisfy the above definition is $\omega_y z - \omega_z y = -v$. **Can we unambiguously find the direction of $\vec{\omega}$ from another argument?**

**My hypothesis:**

If we impose the relation $\vec{L} = \mathcal{I}\ \vec{\omega}$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is the inertia tensor then we might be able to do so. Given $\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times  m \vec{v} = (0,-vz,vy)$ and $\mathcal{I} = m\ \text{diag}\left[(y^2+z^2),(x^2+z^2),(x^2+y^2)\right]$ for a point particle then $\vec{\omega}$ must be parallel to $\vec{L}$ and the ambiguity is lifted.

**The counter-argument:**

The examples below come from *Introduction to Classical Mechanics* by David Morin. The second example is the same that I described above, but it explicitly says that $\vec{\omega}$ points in the $\hat{z}$ direction.

However, when the author explains why the angular momentum is not parallel to $\vec{\omega}$ anymore, he argues that if we look at the particle for a split second we don't know about which axis it is rotating. Then it means we shouldn't know for sure that $\vec{\omega}$ is pointing in the $\hat{z}$ direction and the argument fails.

Shouldn't the vector $\vec{\omega}$ undergo some transformation between the two examples? Sure, if we look at the system for many cycles we'll see that the rotation is about the $z$ axis *on average*, but I don't think it's true for the *instantaneous* angular velocity...

Perhaps there's a better definition for $\vec{\omega}$? I've seen $\vec{\omega} = (\vec{r}\times\vec{v})/r^2$, which means we demand that it is orthogonal to the position $\vec{r}$ (and in the case of a point particle, it means $\vec{L}$ is always parallel to $\vec{\omega}$).

[image: Example from Morin]

Comment: Oops I realized the inertia tensor is not diagonal for a point particle and there's actually an off-diagonal component $\mathcal{I}_{yz} = -m yz/2$ (the only other non zero component if $x=0$). It's even worse because the tensor has no inverse and we can't find $\vec{\omega}$ from $\vec{\omega} = \mathcal{I}^{-1} \vec{L}$. So that doesn't solve the ambiguity.

Comment: w=r x v /r^2, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity

Comment: @Wolphram jonny That's one way to define it, but many textbooks use the definition above. They don't seem consistent with one another. Is one of them "better" than the other?

Comment: I have always heard that it is defined as perpendicular to both v and r, so the two definitions are equivalent as $r . \omega=0$ in the second equation

Comment: Yes but clearly that definition is not used by the example 2 above since $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{\omega}$ is not 0. I'm wondering if their definition is incorrect as it could lead to some inconsistency or if anything goes.

Comment: I understand that r and v must be in the same plane, r is not measured from the origin of coordinates but from the axis of rotation at a position in which both r and v are perpendicular. But my memory might be failing, that is why I did not post it as an answer. I am going to check the stuff and post an answer if I come up with it

Comment: Your very first equation does not define angular velocity.  So at this point you do not have an ambiguity as you do not have the term defined.  The equation does not define w it defines v if given w.  There are standard conventions for measuring w rel to a coord syst.  Those need to be considered too when interpreting equations.